# Creating a List of Unique Items in a Dropdown List

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, unique

I tried searching for a solution to a problem I had and, having resolved it I would like to post it so that it may help others. Every other method of creating a list of unique items from a named range or table involved Power Query's which were not very dynamic, Pivot Tables which have their own pitfalls or VBA's which carry permission limitations when sending to others.

I managed, however, to solve this problem using two additional columns within the target Table.

First I created a 3-column table called **MY_Table** (It must be named for these formulas to work dynamically) which has three headings **ORIGINS**, **FIRST_INST** and **INST_SORTED**

In the table body simply fill in the ORIGINS column with the data required like this (note the numbers in First_Inst start with 4 for 'English' in this example because the Table Headers were on the 3rd row of the worksheet):

[image: Table Setup]

The **FIRST_INST** column is then populated with the following formula which identifies where in the table the first instance of each entry happens:

=IF(SUM(MIN(ROW(MY_TABLE))-1)+MATCH([@ORIGINS],INDIRECT("$"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,(MIN(COLUMN(MY_TABLE))+MATCH(MY_TABLE[[#Headers],[ORIGINS]],MY_TABLE[#Headers],0)-1),4),"1","")&MIN(ROW(MY_TABLE))&":$"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,(MIN(COLUMN(MY_TABLE))+MATCH(MY_TABLE[[#Headers],[ORIGINS]],MY_TABLE[#Headers],0)-1),4),"1","")&ROW()),0)=ROW(),ROW(),0)

The **INST_SORTED** column then has the following formula that populates this column using the integers in **FIRST_INST** in order:

=IF(LARGE([FIRST_INST],SUM(MIN(ROW()-ROW(MY_TABLE)+1)))>0,INDIRECT("$"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,(MIN(COLUMN(MY_TABLE))+MATCH(MY_TABLE[[#Headers],[ORIGINS]],MY_TABLE[#Headers],0)-1),4),"1","")&LARGE([FIRST_INST],SUM(MIN(ROW()-ROW(MY_TABLE)+1)))),"")

Then, since we can't paste this directly into the data validation source, we have a cell somewhere - doesn't matter where - which has the following formula which indicates what range of cells have the unique items within **INST_SORTED**

=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(MY_TABLE)+MATCH(MY_TABLE[[#Headers],[INST_SORTED]],MY_TABLE[#Headers],0)-1,4),"1","")&MIN(ROW(MY_TABLE))&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(MY_TABLE)+MATCH(MY_TABLE[[#Headers],[INST_SORTED]],MY_TABLE[#Headers],0)-1,4),"1","")&SUM(MIN(ROW(MY_TABLE))+SUM(COUNTA(MY_TABLE[INST_SORTED])-COUNTBLANK(MY_TABLE[INST_SORTED])-1))

Finally we create a drop down list data validation and use the above cell as its indirect source  - i.e. the Source would be =INDIRECT(your_cell_here)

The majority of the formulas above retain the exact column and row data so you can change to location of the table, add columns or rows within and out-with the table (and even the names of any of the table headings!) and it keeps on dynamically working a treat.

Mostly it's the technique which I'm putting out there, and I know 365 has some newer commands to combat this limitation. For us Deisel powered Excel users though (I'm on 2003), I hope this is useful to some degree.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using ??

Comment: Old... 2003. I am aware that 365 has new commands to resolve this but not everyone has access to 365.